# Downloading XML data into R

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to read user posts from http://www.propertyforum.com/forum/ into R, once I download the file, xmlTreeParse function is throwing an error.

```
library(XML)
file1 <- "FY12.xml"

download.file("http://www.propertyforum.com/forum/", file1, method="auto")

doc <- xmlTreeParse(file1, useInternalNode = TRUE)
top <- xmlRoot(doc)
```

> ```
>  Error: 1: xmlParseEntityRef: no name 2: xmlParseEntityRef: no name 3:
>  error parsing attribute name 4: attributes construct error 5: Couldn't
>  find end of Start Tag scr line 38 6: StartTag: invalid element name 7:
>  EntityRef: expecting ';' 8: EntityRef: expecting ';' 9: Opening and
>  ending tag mismatch: link line 47 and head 10: Specification mandate
>  value for attribute async 11: attributes construct error 12: Couldn't
>  find end of Start Tag script line 151 13: Opening and ending tag
>  mismatch: div line 147 and script 14: xmlParseEntityRef: no name 15:
>  Specification mandate value for attribute itemscope 16: attributes
>  construct error 17: Couldn't find end of Start Tag ol line 3466 18:
>  Opening and ending tag mismatch: div line 3459 and ol 19:
>  Specification mandate value for attribute async 20: attributes
>  construct error 21: Couldn't find end of Start Tag script line 3906
>  22: Opening and ending tag mismatch: div line 3899 and script 23:
>  Specification mandate value for attribute async 24: attr
> ```

Comment: Um...where's the XML? Do you mean the HTML? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to read the user posts in that url,
I figured we can just do it by

repage = readLines('http://www.indianrealestateboard.com/forums/showthread.php/11812-MT-Bangalore-Real-Estate-discussions-II')

and then grep on the pattern.. however, I am struggling with grep.. please let me know if there is a better way of doing this

Comment: Don't try to parse HTML with regex; you need an HTML parser like the `rvest` package: `library(rvest) ; 'http://www.indianrealestateboard.com/forums/showthread.php/11812-MT-Bangalore-Real-Estate-discussions-II' %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('blockquote.postcontent') %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)`

Comment: Great, this works like a miracle, thanks @alistaire